# Memoization Involving More than one Variable

Tags: recursion, memoization

Good morning.  I would like to know if there is a way to implement memoization if there is more than one variable involved in the memoization; or more accurately, for my problem, have the memoization itself be a function of a second variable.  Let me explain.

I'm working with a certain set of numbers called Hypergeometric Bernoulli Numbers (and down the road the polynomial analogues...) which are defined recursively as

$$B_{N,0}=1$$

$$B_{N,k}=-\binom{N+k}{k}^{-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{N+k}{j}B_{N,j}$$

I had a previous post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235221/faster-more-elegant-way-to-produce-a-recursive-sequence-of-rational-numbers) which helped me in recalling how the memoization process works in Mathematica.  And it produced exactly what I needed; except I need to be able to have my resulting outputs be functions of $N$.  It seems during my previous process, the $N$ is unavailable for evaluation.  How can I amend my previous code to allow the memoized terms to be functions themselves?

Here was my code attempt:
[image]

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can for example memoize a *function* `B[k]` for each value of $k$, so that we can call `B[k][n]` with any argument $n$:

```
B[0] = Function[n, 1];
B[k_Integer /; k >= 1] := B[k] = Function[n,
  Evaluate@Together@FunctionExpand[
    -Sum[Binomial[n+k,j]*B[j][n], {j,0,k-1}]/Binomial[n+k,k]]]
```

Then make an abbreviation, so that `B[n,k]` calls `B[k][n]` for cleaner access:

```
B[n_, k_Integer /; k >= 0] := B[k][n]
```

Test:

```
B[n, 0]
(*    1    *)

B[n, 1]
(*    -1/(1 + n)    *)

B[n, 2]
(*    2/((1 + n)^2 (2 + n))    *)
```

If you now check with `?B` you'll see the memoized functions `B[0]`, `B[1]`, `B[2]`.